# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':segment_analytics-react-native:classpath'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, npm

A problem occurred configuring project ':segment_analytics-react-native'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':segment_analytics-react-native:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
> Required by:
> project :segment_analytics-react-native
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
> > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other p
> rotocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to fin
> d valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s

```
at makeError (D:\test_app\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\test_app\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\test_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\test_app\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

can someone suggest a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

for me, the solution was to install
@segment/sovran-react-native

```
yarn add @segment/sovran-react-native
```